# Is the name Kadesh a verb, and is Kodesh the proper way of spelling it?

Tags: names

My name is Kadesh, and I just finished getting my name trashed by some people saying my name is not a valid Jewish name because it is a verb...is that actually a problem with a Jewish name, and should the name Kadesh actually be "Kodesh"?

Comment: Yes it is, but there's nothing wrong with having a name that's a verb...

Comment: Kadesh in Hebrew is a verb. Transliterations can be tricky things, though. In Aramaic, however, or possibly another Semitic language, it's possible that the vocalization is something that would resemble "K-a-d-e-s-h" when transliterated into English.  But, as @Scimonster said, there's nothing wrong with a name that is in verb form. A good many Jewish names are verbs or not actually grammatically correct anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard of Kadesh as a first name, and Kadesh is indeed a command verb (***Kadesh*** = Make it holy, and ***Kodesh*** = is holy), **but** why is that a reason for mockery? 
The famous Jewish name "Go'el" (גואל) is also a verb for example, future tense verbs are also extremely famous, such as the patriarchs Yaacov (יעקב) and Itzhak (יצחק)

At least from the "verb" point of view, you can be relaxed.

Among others, the verb Kadesh was used to name a biblical (also [a settlement today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(Israel))) [city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh), the [Israeli operation](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99) during the 1956 war with Egypt, the ancient [battle of Kadesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kadesh),

BTW, name trashing is common practice and identifier for people that smart fellows keep their distance from (since they are worthy of the adjectives you have provided in the question) ...

Comment: http://www.biblical-baby-names.com/meaning-of-kadesh.html

Comment: http://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Kadesh.html

Comment: Ah thanks for the reply, this seems like a decent site.. the other forums and websites I tried to join were a little... "WE ARE MORE JEWISH THEN YOU, har har har " ... Really weird... weird people...

Comment: @Kadesh - Welcome, I'm rather new here too... if you wish to contact me personally you are most welcome. I am a Baal Tshuva from Israel, very enthusiastic about the Tora, Halacha and helping other with the little info I've managed to gather so far :)

Answer (score 5):

1 - Your name is beautiful and holy.

2 - I personally know someone else with this name.

3 - [Bais Hamedrash Shem V'Ever - page 195](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20790&st=&pgnum=205&hilite=) says this name is from the [Yemei Habainaim](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D) which is known as the dark ages. Bais Hamedrash Shem V'Ever says it is spelled with a Yud. קדיש

4 - [Tiv Gitin](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37332&st=&pgnum=60) at the end of letter Kuf mentions the name Kadish. Tuv Gittin says it is spelled without the Yud. קדש

Comment: Kaddish and Kaddesh could be different names (chirik vs tzeirei)

Comment: :o !               ............

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, "Kadesh" is a noun, also (The answer stating that it is a verb is **also** correct, but it is not the only interpretation.)

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(Israel)):

> Kadesh or Qadhesh in Classical (Hebrew: קָדֵשׁ‎), also known as
>   Qadesh-Barneaʿ (קָדֵשׁ בַּרְנֵעַ),[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(Israel)) is a location mentioned in the
>   Hebrew Bible where a number of historical events took place. Kadesh
>   was an important site in Israelite history. It was the chief site of
>   encampment for the Israelites during their wandering in the wilderness
>   of Zin (Deut. 1:46); it was from Kadesh that the spies were sent out
>   into Canaan (Num. 13:1-26); The first failed attempt to take the land
>   was made from Kadesh (Num. 14:40-45); Moses disobediently struck the
>   rock that brought forth water at this location (Num. 20:11); Miriam
>   and Aaron died and were buried nearby (Num. 20:1, 22-29); and Moses
>   sent envoys to the King of Edom from Kadesh (Num. 20:14), asking for
>   permission to let the Israelites pass through his terrain. The Edomite
>   king denied this request.
>
> Kadesh-Barnea is also a key feature in the common biblical formula
>   delineating the southern border of Israel (cf. Num. 34:4, Josh. 15:3,
>   Ezek. 47:19 et al.)[2] and thus its identification is key to
>   understanding both the ideal and geopolitically realized borders of
>   ancient Israel.

So, you can see, that the place *Kadesh* has significant geographic status in several places in the Torah as well as elsewhere in *Tanac"h*. The torah sometimes uses the full name *Kadesh Barne'a* (I don't know the etymology of the term "barne'a") and sometimes the shortened term *kadesh*. They refer to the same place.

EIther explanation, your name is not a source of mockery, whether it is a verb, noun or adjective, for that matter. (Many names are adjectives, BTW - so what?) If it makes you feel better, you can now prove that your name is a noun.

Comment: This explanation is brought in the first answer as well

Comment: Well I'm glad to see i'm not being brutally attacked here.... I joined a few forums and chat rooms, as I don't have much going on at the moment and it seems every thing I post in those forums or chat rooms gets attacked.

Comment: @Kadesh Lesson to be learned. Generally people who attack others for no reason have their own faults that they don't see. Ignore them.